# Network Error (tcp_error) After long file processing in grails app on Tomcat 7

Tags: tomcat, grails, connection, timeout

I have a web app created in Grails which is deployed on a Tomcat 7 server. The application reads a csv file and performs some heavy operations, where the requests can take up to 5-10 minutes to complete. When run on a small subset of data, the application performs fine. However, if I use a large set of data, and the request takes more than roughly 3 minutes, I receive the following error:

```
Network Error (tcp_error)  

A communication error occurred: ""  
The Web Server may be down, too busy, or experiencing other 
problems preventing it from responding to requests. 
You may wish to try again at a later time.
```

Is this a Tomcat problem? Or is the timeout based on a client side browser property?

Ive tried setting the connectionTimeout and the disableUploadTimeout properties in Tomcat's server.xml, but so far no luck.

Any help would be really appreciated!

Answer (score 0):

I found this [related question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12932136/how-to-avoid-client-firewall-closing-connection-because-inactivity-while-process) talking about firewall closing the connection, I think you are experiencing something similiar.

If you are using Grails 2.3 you can take advantage of the [Asynchronous Programming](http://grails.org/doc/2.3.0.M1/guide/async.html) feature to perform heavy operations and keep the connection alive (for example send an Ajax call every 10 sec while waiting for the process to complete) to avoid a timeout.

Answer (score 0):

What do you see in the Catalina.out file(

```
tail -f -n100 /var/log/tomcat7/catalina.out
```

another source of information could be the system logs:

```
dmesg --ctime
```

And the last option that I can think of is:

```
netstat
```